# Problem with deleting account and documents with Firestore

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete the user account and all of its documents in Firestore, but with asynchronous queries, Firebase deletes the account before all documents.

Because of that I get an auth error because when firestorm delete the lasts documents, the user no longer exist.

```
db.collection("users").document(self.user.uid).collection("sachets").getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err{
        print("Erreur de lecture : \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
            db.collection("users").document(self.user.uid).collection("sachets").document(document.documentID).delete(){ err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("    Probleme de suppression des docuemnts \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("    Documents supprimés")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
self.user?.delete { error in
    if let error = error {
        print("    Probleme de suppression du compte Utilisateur \(error)")
    } else {
        print("    Utilisateur supprimé")
    }
}
```

Someone can tell me how to do ?
thanks

Comment: please format your code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I set up a test-project and solve this. You also need to make sure to remove all the data from the user fields. For instance, if you're having `name`, `age` etc... at the `user` node.

**First** I created a function to fetch the current users `uid`:

```
func currentUser() -> String {
    return Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
}
```

**Then** I created a function to remove all the data for the logged in user. This will first remove all the subcollection data and then it will remove the document for the `userID`.

To handle asynchronous methods you can use `DispatchGroup` to notify when all the asynchronous calls are done.

*One side note*: Make sure to **NEVER** force-unwrap a value if you can't 100% guarantee there are documents. Otherwise, your app will likely crash. To solve this either use `guard` or `if let` to solve this problem.

```
// Where "user" is the result from currentUser()
func removeData(from user: String) {
    db.collection("users").document(user).collection("sachets").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle error
        } else if let documents = snapshot?.documents {
            // Using if let to see if there are documents

            // Time to delete all the subCollection for the user
            self.deleteSubCollectionData(for: user, documents, completion: {

                // Once that done, make sure to delete all the fields on the highest level.
                self.db.collection("users").document(user).delete(completion: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle error
                    } else {
                        // Delete the account
                        self.deleteAccount()
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}

// This function will remove the subCollectionData
fileprivate func deleteSubCollectionData(for user: String, _ documents: [QueryDocumentSnapshot], completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    documents.forEach({
        group.enter()
        self.db.collection("users").document(user).collection("sachets").document($0.documentID).delete(completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle error
            }
            group.leave()
        })
    })

    // Once the dispatchGroup is done...
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

And in the end...

```
func deleteAccount() {
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Deleted account")
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't remove all the levels of data, then there still will be data in Firestore.

Comment: Thanks ... i'll try this

Comment: Yeah, go ahead. One thing I didn't mention is that you need to make sure to remove all the user data before removing the account. IF there would occur anything unusual. For instance if there would be an error removing the data. Then we don't want to remove the user account before fixing that problem. So removing the account would always be the last thing to do.

Comment: Its good for the removed documents, but I have a new problem when he try to delete the account, I got the error "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."

Comment: Glad that I could help you out! I found this, I hope you can dig in a bit to understand why :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749206/7653367
Good luck! @laurentespinosa

Comment: It's OK ... I solve the problem asking the password for confirmation delete, and I reauthenticate it. All is Good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDocuments()` method is asynchronous, so you should delete the account only after having deleted the documents.

Just put the `user?.delete` method inside the `getDocuments()` callback

```
db.collection("users").document(self.user.uid).collection("sachets").getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err{
        print("Erreur de lecture : \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
            db.collection("users").document(self.user.uid).collection("sachets").document(document.documentID).delete(){ err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("    Problème de suppression des documents \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("    Documents supprimés")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    self.user?.delete { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("    Problème de suppression du compte Utilisateur \(error)")
        } else {
            print("    Utilisateur supprimé")
        }
    }
}
```